# How we can remove/change the label of Sales Order status from top of the record?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, erp

I want to either change the sales order status label or remove it from top of the SO through suite script.
But still I m not able to figure out how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set/change this field in script with :

```
salesOrderRecord.setValue({fieldId: "orderstatus",value: "your value"});
```

Value possible for SO :

```
_pendingApproval
_pendingFulfillment
_cancelled
_partiallyFulfilled
_pendingBillingPartFulfilled
_pendingBilling
_fullyBilled
_closed
_undefined
```

Comment: While using this logic to change the status from Pending Billing to Fully Billed NetSuite giving this error- Invalid orderstatus reference key _fullyBilled.

Comment: Where is the documentation that shows these possible statuses?

Comment: https://system.na2.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/srbrowser/Browser2021_1/schema/enum/salesorderorderstatus.html?mode=package